# Phantomjscloud login and download JSON file

Tags: phantomjs

I would like to download file from my dashboard which is only accessible with login details. I am trying to use PhantomJSCloud for this.

So, there is request.json for login to dashboard:

```
{
    "url": "https://example.com/sign",
    "overseerScript":'let _user="username"; let _pass="pass"; await page.waitForSelector("input#username"); await page.type("input#username",_user,{delay:50}); await page.type("input#password",_pass,{delay:50}); page.click("button[type=submit]"); await page.waitForNavigation();',
}
```

It works fine. After logging in, a page is loaded where the JSON file is available for download. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<a download="" type="application/json" href="/personal/data/json" class="specials">File.json</a>
```

When I'm logged into the dashboard and I click on the File.json link, a file called file-currenttimestamp.json is downloaded.

Is there any way to make PhantomJSCloud click on File.json and save the file to my FTP?